# How to modify ViewComponent result in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, filter, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I want to modify the result of `ViewComponent` by using a filter as we do with MVC `ActionFiltersAttribute`. I've tried `ActionFilterAttribute` but it's not working with `ViewComponent` even it's not calling.

```
public class BeforeCheckoutCallFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Equals("ProductDetails_AttributeChange", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            //Business logic
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm registering this filter inside `Startup.cs`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add<BeforeCheckoutCallFilter>();
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to get the `ViewComponent` result and modify it as we were used to doing with MVC filters?

**Updated:** I want to intercept the call after returning `IViewComponentResult`.

**Note:** I've got know that the `ViewComponent` does not take part in the controller lifecycle, which means we can’t use filters in a view component.

Comment: You can intercept the view component invoking to get its result `IHtmlContent` or before invoking it but looks like it's hard to get the `IViewComponentResult` (the direct result returned by your view component). The default invoker is `DefaultViewComponentInvoker` has no extensibility points to intercept the `IViewComponentResult` as you can see here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ViewComponents/DefaultViewComponentInvoker.cs#L67 - Unless you copy the code there into your custom view component invoker class.

Comment: I don't want to make a change in ViewComponent. I want to intercept it.

Comment: when you compare it to action filters, I think it need to be able to intercept the `IViewComponentResult`. Intercepting can be done at various points so that cannot say exactly what you want. As I commented, at the point of intercepting the call after returning `IViewComponentResult`, it's hard to implement. But at the point of before calling the `InvokeAsync` or `Invoke` or after the invocation (with `IViewComponentResult` run) returning an `IHtmlContent`, you can have a fairly simple solution.

Comment: I want to intercept the call after returning IViewComponentResult.

Comment: yes, so it's hard due to the default invoker implementation in the source code I shared in my first comment. Note that after returning `IViewComponentResult` means you can get that result (by intercepting). That result will be executed and you have the final `IHtmlContent` which can be obtained by intercepting `IViewComponentHelper.InvokeAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for direct interception of ViewComponents, as it does not take part of the request pipeline. From the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0#creating-a-view-component):

> A view component class:
>
> - **Doesn't take part in the controller lifecycle, which means you can't use filters in a view component**

But you can do it indirectly by [invoking the ViewComponent from an Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0#invoking-a-view-component-directly-from-a-controller) instead. Then decorate the Action with your Filter:

```
[BeforeCheckoutCall]
public IActionResult Checkout()
{
    return ViewComponent("PriorityList", new { maxPriority = 3, isDone =     false });
}
```